# sending me duplicate data

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

Im implementing dropzone um page, and in each iamge i need to add a title and description, but when i try to send more than one photo, instead of each request or image having one title is giving me all the same name.

my code:

```
 $('#submit').on('click',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     myDropzone.processQueue();
 });

 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
 // Dropzone class:
 var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", {
    url: "/products",
    autoProcessQueue:false,
    previewTemplate: "<div class=\"dz-preview dz-file-preview\">\n  " +
    "<div class=\"dz-image\"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div>\n " +
    "<input type=\"text\" id=\"title\" data-dz-title name=\"dz-title\">\n " +
    "<input type=\"text\" id=\"url\" name=\"dz-url\">\n " +
    " <div class=\"dz-details\">"

}).on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append("title", $('#title').val());
});
```

Comment: `.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
$( "#title" ).each(function() {
  formData.append("title", $( this ).val());
});
 `

Comment: doesnt work, just try it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ids are not unique, therefore you can't reliably get the input data from the ID selector.

Change your IDs on your inputs in the template to classes like this:

```
previewTemplate: "<div class='dz-preview dz-file-preview'>\n  " +
    "<div class='dz-image'><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div>\n " +
    "<input type='text' class='dz-brand' value='This is the text'> \n " +
    "<input type='text' class='dz-url'>\n </div>"
```

Then add the parameters with the sending event, this will get the input values at the time of upload.

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append('brand'      , $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-brand').val());
    formData.append('url'        , $(file.previewElement).find('.dz-url').val());
    formData.append('description', 'small detail');
});
```